# Ajuda com função re.search

Tags: python

Eu tenho um **for** que joga num **dicionário** pra verificar o que o usuário digitou pra ver é igual, pra se for chamar uma **função**... o for em questão:

**FOR**

```
for x in abrir:
                if(re.search(abrir[x], user_response, re.IGNORECASE)):
                    print(abrir_coisas(user_response))
```

(se tiver um jeito de fazer isso num if eu agradeceria também, mas não é essa minha questão agora)

No **dicionário** em questão eu tenho isso:

```
abrir = {....26:'\\babrir notepad\\b', 27:'\\babra notepad\\b',...60:'\\b\\wabrir notepad\+\+', 61:'\\b\\wabra notepad\+\+'...
```

Que por sua vez joga pra isso na **função**:

```
elif ((re.search('\\babrir notepad\\b', user_response, re.IGNORECASE)) or (re.search('\\babra notepad\\b', user_response, re.IGNORECASE))):
                if file == "notepad.exe":
```

**e isso**

```
elif ((re.search('\\b\\wabrir notepad\+\+', user_response, re.IGNORECASE)) or (re.search('\\b\\wabra notepad\+\+', user_response, re.IGNORECASE))):
                if file == "notepad++.exe":
```

Só que ele SEMPRE está abrindo o NOTEPAD e não o NOTEPAD++ não importa o que eu faça, alguém poderia me ajudar a resolver isso? Imagino que eu esteja esquecendo de usar algum código simples, só que eu não estou conseguindo encontrar ele. Obrigado.